# Why retrieve firebase data value not view after publish google play but build emulator show retrieve data?

Tags: android

first image testing mode/ develop mobile emulator show data from firebase[image]

[image]

second image after publish google play data nopt show

Comment: you've posted 2 images here without any code, it's impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Generated signed APK or Bundle is signed with different SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys then the debug apk. Did you entered somewhere the SHA-1 or SHA-256 on firebase? Make sure that if you set SHA-1 or SHA-256 keys on Firebase, you set the production ones. You can get them from the keystore that you used to sign the application.